# Production Environment Error: Does not resolve to a valid user id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, environment

I finished a working app that allows my user to login with Facebook then simultaneously post to their blog website and a Facebook page wall on submit. This works fine in my development environment (localhost) but when I pushed it up to production I get the following error when trying to post to the pages wall:

```
1.234523452345234E+14 does not resolve to a valid user ID
```

The number shown is almost identical to the page (not user) id of the page I am attempting to post to. I assume since you must act as the page when performing actions on the page that the page is the user. Any ideas why this would break in a new environment? I did update my app configuration to point to the correct canvas urls.

- User can successfully login.
- I can access the user id and page id.

I noticed the page id is getting reformatted:
`12345234523452340` becomes `1.234523452345234E+14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it back to the whole number:

```
number_format(1.234523452345234E+14,0,'','')
```

Comment: This worked! I threw in an echo before and after to show the id. On localhost, the id was fine. In production it was screwed up. What server configuration would screw up a number like that?

Comment: Not sure why it differ in both cases :-/ Probably its returning the number not a string so it can convert it may be converting to the exponential form, not sure.